# Is it a problem if I have a flag that's been pending for over a day?

Tags: discussion

So, I flagged [this question](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/176827/what-is-this-font-used-in-realm-of-the-mad-god) for being off-topic, and the flag has been pending for **2 days**. Why? Here's a relevant screenshot.

[image]

Comment: Obviously you never flagged for closure on Stack Overflow. This might take weeks, months and sometimes eternity.

Comment: Anyway this probably belongs to the meta site of gaming.